# accessing structures in different source files

Tags: c, structure

I want to access data from a struct used in file1.c and access the data in file2.c

I have declared

```
in file1.c

     struct value
    {
        unsigned char time[6];
        unsigned char date[6];
        unsigned char number[6];
    } entry;
```

where the struct gets filled by values and then want to use the structure in file2.c

> ```
>     time[0]= entry.time[0];
>      date[0]=entry.date[0];
>       number[0]=entry.number[0];
> ```

How should i use  structure scope such that it can be accessed in file2.c too.?

Comment: You do knoq the difference between declaration and definition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `extern` keyword and declare the `struct` variable in the new file also.

```
extern struct value entry;
```

Comment: Thank you very much @Sakthi Kumar.So doing that i can access the values that gets filled in file1.c right.